# how to activate a background app to service a TCP/IP stream with another nearby device?

Tags: iphone, ios, bonjour

I have two devices, a 'manager' iphone and a 'worker' iphone, nearby each other.

A 'worker' app on one iPhone needs to respond to a request for data from a 'manager' app on another nearby iPhone, by Bluetooth or WIFI.

The worker app publishes itself as a Bonjour service.

The manager app on the 2nd iPhone finds worker app service by Bonjour, and tries to establsh a TCP/IP data connection.

But if the worker app is in background mode, how can it be awakened to begin servicing the TCP/IP stream with the remote manager app?

(I'm a Bonjour newbie, but an iPhone streaming oldbie.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Apple's Core bluetooth (Bluetooth Low Energy - BTLE) because it works in the background.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295
[See Apple core bluetooth framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295)

Answer (score 2):

Apple don't provide a background mode for generic servers, so if you want to publish to the App Store and your app doesn't fit one of the other background modes, you're out of luck.  If you don't have to go through the App Store, then you can use one of several hacks to make your application run in the background, such as abusing the VOIP or media player background modes.

Comment: I plan to use the external-accessory background mode, because we'll be reading data from it.  Then, I want a master app on a 2nd, nearby iOS device to be able to read this data from the 1st device through a TCP/IP connection.  But if the 2nd device's TCP/IP service app is in the background, I need it to go active to service the data request.

Comment: @Jim's answer covers this case as well. You cannot solve this problem without user intervention to re-launch your application. If your "master app" stays in the foreground (or at least is in the background no more than 10 minutes, so you can use a "long-running background task" to stay alive) then it's solvable. Otherwise it isn't for App Store deployed apps.

Comment: We will have an external accessory connected to the iOS device.  The Apple doc seems to imply that external accessory updates will cause iOS to run a corresponding delegate even in a background app, which is given a 10 second time 'budget' to get work done.  (More can be requested, but is discouraged by Apple.)

Comment: But I cannot find a way to have an iOS device cause a method to run on a 2nd device in an App Store app.